# move dynamic body object in box2d when touchbegin

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d, game-physics

I am creating a game like bounce ball using box2d in cocos2d-x. I created a dynamic body object and i want it to move when touch began. I am using the following code to move the dynamic body but it is not moving. Please anyone could help me to solve the problem.

```
bullet2=CCSprite::create("block.png");
bullet2->setPosition(ccp(2740, 1220));
this->addChild(bullet2,0);

ballBodyDefB.type=b2_dynamicBody;
ballBodyDefB.position.Set(2740/PTM_RATIO, 1170/PTM_RATIO);
ballBodyDefB.userData=bullet2;
ballBodyDefB.gravityScale=0;
_bullet=_world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDefB);

b2PolygonShape bulletshape;
bulletshape.SetAsBox(bullet2->getContentSize().width/PTM_RATIO/2,
                     bullet2->getContentSize().height/PTM_RATIO/2);

b2FixtureDef b_bullet ;
b_bullet.shape = &bulletshape;
b_bullet.density = 1.0f;
b_bullet.friction = 0.1f;
b_bullet.restitution = 0.0;
_bullet->CreateFixture(&b_bullet);
```

CCTouchbegan:

```
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(0, -450);
_block->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, _block->GetPosition());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi moving the sprite which follow b2body is easy. You need to attach Sprite to the b2body.userData and in box2d world step synchronize the position and rotation of your sprite with your b2body.
I can't answer directly your question, please post your code and what version of cocos2d-x you have for more details:

Check if your code contain code about: (**depend on cocos2d-x version**, you use CCSprite which is deprecated in 3.2, we use Sprite only anyway)

- box2d world (you already have _world)
- _world step iteration
- syncing sprite position with b2body

Anyway you can find more details at these links:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Box2D and http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Getting_Started_with_Cocos2d-x